# Fastest way to replace space with an unused character and add space in between all characters

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, text-files

What is a fast way to:

1. Replace space with an unused unicode character.
2. Add spaces in between all characters

I've tried:

```
$ python3 -c "print (open('test.txt').read().replace(' ', u'\uE000').replace('', ' '))" > test.spaced.txt
```

But when I tried it on a 6GB textfile with 90 Million lines, it's really slow.

Simply reading the file after opening it takes really long:

```
$ time python3 -c "print (open('test.txt').read())"
```

Assume that my machine has more than enough RAM to handle the inflated file,

**Is there a way to do it with sed / awk / bash tools?**

**Is there a faster way to do the replacement and addition faster in Python?**

Comment: What do you mean by "really long"? You're inflating a 1.2 GB file to >2.4 GB with over a billion replace operations; how fast do you expect this to be?

Comment: There must be a better/faster way =)

Comment: You have two time-consuming operations: 1) disk i/o. 2) Allocating the memory for multiple 1.2GB strings. There is nothing you can do about (1). For (2), try reading a smaller amount, say 1MB, in a loop. It might go a little faster.

Comment: try `sed 's/ //g; s/./& /g' test.txt > test.spaced.txt`

Comment: also, is it okay to simply add a space for non-space characters? `sed 's/[^ ]/& /g'` will do for that

Comment: Having `u'\uE000'` to replace the spaces is crucial.

Comment: All string methods are actually developed in highly optimised C, so this is hardly a Python issue. Running this in a loop, as suggested by Rob, might slow things down, necause you will dramatically increase the number of Python-level function calls and C-Python callbacks.

Comment: @alvas okay, so how does that `sed` command compare in timing with `python` solution?

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to do this without writing a new file?  Just write a generator that reads characters from the file and spews characters according to your rules?  Then the conversion time wouldn't matter; just the consumption speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, using the tools specially designed for text processing is faster than invoking a script written in a general-purpose interpreted language such as Python.

**SED** doesn't support Unicode escape sequences, but it is possible to pass the actual characters using [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04):

```
sed -i -e "s/ /$(printf '\uE000')/g; s/\(.\)/ \1 /g" file
```

**Perl** is my favorite, because it is very flexible. It is also much better for text processing than Python:

> The Perl languages borrow features from other programming languages
>   including C, shell script (sh), AWK, and sed... They provide
>   powerful text processing facilities without the arbitrary data-length
>   limits of many contemporary Unix commandline tools,... facilitating
>   easy manipulation of text files.

*(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl))*

Example:

```
perl -CSDL -p -i -e 's/ /\x{E000}/g ; s/(.)/ \1 /g' file
```

Note, the `-CSDL` option enables UTF-8 for the output.

There is also an *AWKward* way of doing this using GNU AWK version 4.1.0 or newer:

```
gawk -i inplace '{
a = gsub(/ /, "\xee\x80\x80");
a = gensub(/(.)/, " \\1 ", "g");
print a; }' file
```

But I wouldn't recommend for obvious reasons.

I doubt that anyone would claim that a specific tool, or algorithm is the fastest one, as there are plenty of factors that may affect the performance, - hardware, the way the tools are compiled, tool versions, the kernel version, etc. Perhaps, the best way to find the right tool, or algorithm is to benchmark. I don't think it necessary to mention the `time` command.

Comment: "invoking a script written in a general-purpose interpreted language such as Python" – Python's string methods are pure C for the most part, there is almost no Python runtime involved in his code,

Comment: The sed and perl solutions are missing the second step to add spaces in between all character.